# jolt transform with nested object

Tags: apache-nifi, jolt

```
    [
  {
    "cluster_id": "0125-175512-node489",
    "custom_tag": {
      "app_name": "testing1",
      "total_time": 32
    }
  },
  {
    "cluster_id": "0125-175512-node489",
    "custom_tag": {
      "app_name": "testing2",
      "total_time": 34
    }
  }
]
```

I want o/p to be like this.

1) add one constant new field "new_addition"
2) copy nested value "custom_tag.app_name" to one level up.
3) copy nested value "custom_tag.total_time" to one level up, but attribute name is different "time_to_finish".

I am not able to figure out jolt-spec for this.

```
    [
  {
    "cluster_id": "0125-175512-node489",
    "app_name": "testing1",
    "new_addition": "new const value",
    "time_to_finish": 32,
    "custom_tag": {
      "app_name": "testing1",
      "total_time": 32
    }
  },
  {
    "cluster_id": "0125-175512-node489",
    "app_name": "testing2",
    "new_addition": "new const value",
    "time_to_finish": 34,
    "custom_tag": {
      "app_name": "testing2",
      "total_time": 34
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

following worked.

```
[{
  "operation": "shift",
  "spec": {
    "@": "&",
    "*": {
      "custom_tag": {
        "app_name": "&3[&2].app_name",
        "total_time": "&3[&2].time_to_finish"
      }
    }
  }
}, {
  "operation": "default",
  "spec": {
    "root[]": {
      "*": {
        "new_addition": "1"
      }
    }
  }
}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are having **`new_addition`** attribute with value to the flow file.

**`Try with this Jolt spec:`**

```
[{
"operation": "shift",
"spec": {
    "*": "&", // get all elements
    "custom_tag": {
        "app_name": "app_name", //copy app_name to one level up
        "total_time": "time_to_finish", //copy total_time to one level up and change name.
        "@": "&" //get all the struct elements as is
    }
}
}, {
    "operation": "default",
    "spec": {
        "new_addition": "${new_addition}" //get the attribute value and add new_addition element to top level.
    }
}]
```

**`Output:`**

```
{
  "cluster_id" : "0125-175512-node489",
  "custom_tag" : {
    "app_name" : "testing2",
    "total_time" : 34
  },
  "app_name" : "testing2",
  "time_to_finish" : 34,
  "new_addition" : "new_addition"
}
```

**`Jolt transform Processor config:`**

[image]

**`Validation:`**

[image]

Comment: hello, it works perfectly when input is a single json element. but if input is an array, it doesnt work. I am getting this as an o/p   => {
  "0" : {
    "cluster_id" : "0125-175512-node489",
    "custom_tag" : {
      "app_name" : "testing1",
      "total_time" : 32
    }
  },
  "1" : {
    "cluster_id" : "0125-175512-node489",
    "custom_tag" : {
      "app_name" : "testing2",
      "total_time" : 34
    }
  },
  "new_addition" : "testing123"
}